# How can I get ALL records with criteria?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm having a tough time with this Access SQL...  I would like ALL active CustomerIDs to appear, whether the OrderDate matches or not, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT 
    tblCustomers_PullLists.CustomerID, 
    tblCustomers_PullLists.Title, 
    tblCustomers_PullLists.Active, 
    tblCustomers.FullName, 
    tblOrders.OrderDate, 
    tblCustomers.Notes
FROM 
    (
        (
            tblCustomers_PullLists 
            INNER JOIN 
            tblOrderDetails 
                ON tblCustomers_PullLists.Title = tblOrderDetails.Title
        ) 
        INNER JOIN 
        tblOrders 
            ON tblOrderDetails.OrderNumber = tblOrders.ID
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN 
    tblCustomers 
        ON tblCustomers_PullLists.CustomerID = tblCustomers.ID
WHERE (((tblCustomers_PullLists.Active)=Yes) 
    AND ((tblOrders.OrderDate)=[Please enter order date]))
ORDER BY tblCustomers_PullLists.CustomerID;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that your query has

```
(stuff) LEFT JOIN tblCustomers
```

If you want all customers to appear then you probably want a RIGHT JOIN, not a LEFT JOIN.

The other issue is the OrderDate. Customers without orders for that date will have NULL OrderDate values, so you may have to change your WHERE condition from...

```
(tblOrders.OrderDate)=[Please enter order date]
```

...to...

```
(((tblOrders.OrderDate)=[Please enter order date]) OR (tblOrders.OrderDate IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case the filter

```
AND ((tblOrders.OrderDate)=[Please enter order date])
```

does not make any sense.

Remove that part of the where cluase, and you should get all active Customers.

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with that - unfortunately I need that filter, though.

Comment: ...I realize I accidentally took OrderDate out of the Select statement while trying to make this a tad easier to look at - it's been added back in.